How do I add spaces in-between when doing so in an edit of @maketitle
I have a piece of code that i want to have have a blank line space worth of text between title and author, author and date, and in between date and content. I have tried some methods, using \\, \newline, but these don't even work for me. Can someone help me get the desired result i want?
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{{\centering
    \@title \\ 
    \@author \\ 
    \@date \\
}}
\makeatother

\setlength\parindent{.25cm} 


% }

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\refstepcounter{section}{\centering\textsc{\Roman{section}. #1}\par}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Where is it found in the wild?}

Loggerhead turtles are located worldwide primarily in subtropical and temperate regions of the Atlantic, Pacific, and Indian Oceans, and the Mediterranean Sea. They also live in Argentina, and from Chile to Alaska.
\end{document}


Maybe \renewcommand{\maketitle} {{\centering     \@title \\~\\     \@author \\~\\     \@date \\~\\ }}

Does replacing \\  by \\[\baselineskip] gives you the expected result?

You can specify the vertical spacing by \[x],
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{{\centering
    \@title \\[2\baselineskip] 
    \@author \\[24pt] 
    \@date \\[12pt]
}}
\makeatother

% }

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Where is it found in the wild?}

Loggerhead turtles are located worldwide primarily in subtropical and temperate regions of the Atlantic, Pacific, and Indian Oceans, and the Mediterranean Sea. They also live in Argentina, and from Chile to Alaska.
\end{document}

which produces

